# Merge rows in a CSV to a column

Tags: python

I am new in python, I have one CSV file, it has more than 1000 rows, I want to merge particular rows and move those rows to another column, can any one help?

This is the source csv file I have:

[image: Source CVS file]

I want to move emails  under members column with comma separator, like this image:

[image: Output]

Comment: This is not a valid CSV file, it may say .csv at the end, but it's not structured as one

Comment: @MenyIssakov There is (sadly) no real centrally agreed-upon standard for CSV files. If it can be interpreted as rows with values separated by commas (or perhaps some other delimiter), it's a CSV. This file would read just fine with the `csv` module in Python for instance.

Answer (score 1):

To read csv files in Python, you can use the csv module. This code does the merging you're looking for.

```py
import csv

output = []  # this will store a list of new rows

with open('test.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    
    # read the first line of the input as the headers
    header = next(reader)
    output.append(header)
    
    # we will build up groups and their emails
    emails = []
    group = []
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 1 and row[1]:   # "UserGroup" is given
            if group:
                group[-1] = ','.join(emails)
            group = row
            output.append(group)
            emails = []
        else:  # it isn't, assume this is an email
            emails.append(row[0])

    group[-1] = ','.join(emails)

# now write a new file
with open('new.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(output)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But i am getting below error.

 if row[1]:   # "UserGroup" is given
       ~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: if i do any changes on csv and save it directly means , the above code is working perfectly, otherwise  the code is not working

Comment: It might be that the original file you are working with doesn't have blanks in that row, but rather just the one value without extra commas. I've added a check for that.

Comment: For future reference, it is more useful to paste the actual text of the CSV from a text editor than what it looks like when opened in Excel.

Comment: i have attached text editor format in this link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040358/merge-mulitiples-rows-in-text-editor-file-and-move-to-single-column